# Locking Behavior Task.WaitAny vs. Task.Result

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, async-await, task

**Given Scenario:**

I'm struggling with some locking issues. Below is a simplified code which describes the the situation in the given code. I need to use a async method inside a non async Method which should return the resulting string of the `GetContentFromDbAsync()` method

**Given Task:**

```
myTask = Task.Run(async () => await GetContentFromDbAsync(key));
```

Now My Question is there A difference in locking behavior when doing these variations ? Task.Result Does lock the thread is this also true for option 2 ?

**Option 1:**

```
string result = myTask.ConfigureAwait(false)).Result;
```

In the MSDN I can read:

> Accessing the property's get accessor blocks the calling thread until
>   the asynchronous operation is complete; it is equivalent to calling
>   the Wait method.

**Option 2:**

```
string result ;
myTask.ContinueWith( (t) => { result = t; },TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
Task.WaitAny(myTask)
```

For Task.WaitAny no such hint is written in the MSDN, are they just missing it or does it have another locking behavior, and why?

So would `Task.WaitAny` have a better locking behavior regarding at pot. deadlocks?

Comment: Why are you stuck calling a async method from a sync one. What is preventing you from caling/writing a synchronous version of `GetContentFromDbAsync()` or making the code calling `GetContentFromDbAsync()` async too? If you are using async because "it is faster" the way you are doing it will be worse performing than had you done it fully synchronous or had done it fully asynchronous, mixing both gives you the performance losses from both styles and you don't get any of the gains.

Comment: Because the method is used inside a razor view as HTML Extension.

Comment: Ok, that explains why you can't make it async, why cant you call `GetContentFromDb()`?

Comment: Because its mongodb and it only has a async interface

Comment: @BoasEnkler: ASP.NET vNext supports `async` Razor. Until then, the best approach is to confine `async` to your controller's generation of viewmodels, and use HTML helpers only to translate from VMs to HTML (synchronously).

Answer (score 2):

`Task.WaitAny` is blocking as well. Note that the MSDN comment on `Result` states that "it is equivalent to calling the Wait method". So calling `Result`, `Wait`, `WaitAny` or any other form of waiting blocks the current thread until the async method finishes execution.

Comment: ok just meets my expectation but was unsure as missing the hint there